# Passing sparkSession to function in Scala - Spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I'm migrating from Spark 1.6 version to 2.1 and looking at the below 
    mentioned function in Scala, trying to figure out, how do we pass 
    SparkSession variable to the function instead of sqlContext -

```
private def readHiveTable(sqlContext: HiveContext, hiveTableNm: String, 
hiveWorkDb: String): DataFrame
```

I mean, would sqlContext change to sparkSession ? what is the right way to pass this variable in Spark 2.1 ? may be something like -

```
private def readHiveTable(spark: sparkSession, hiveTableNm: String, 
hiveWorkDb: String): DataFrame
```

**UPDATE**

Resolved it by passing - 
spark: SparkSession instead of sqlContext: HiveContext